# Credit check for refinance inquiry?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, refinance

I'm thinking of refinancing my mortgage. I called my current lender, and was given a quote for a refinance with a lower interest rate, and $1200 in closing costs. Now I'm trying to shop around for other offers. I called Quicken Loans, and they didn't want to even give me any quotes that included closing costs without running a credit check.

I realized once I apply for a loan from a company, they should run a check on me, of course. But to even inquire about loans to decide where to apply? Is this right?

I'm concerned that these credit checks, if I agreed, will ding my credit score, and undermine what I can eventually get.

Comment: Did you ask them if it's a hard pull or a soft pull?

Comment: I did. He couldn't answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When shopping for a mortgage, you get a grace period where all credit pulls related to mortgage shopping in 14 days only count as one credit pull.    Having other banks pull your credit to get a quote should not additionally affect your credit because you just had a bank pull your credit for the first quote.

Comment: He is really asking why do they need to pull your credit just to tell you the closing fees.

Comment: @Vitalik: I guess I focused on this part of the question: "if I agreed, will ding my credit score, and undermine what I can eventually get."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's helpful. But I am surprised that they'd need to pull credit just to let me know the fees. If the fees are outrageous, why go through with the discussion at all?